# MDC-Web: mdc-text-field--outlined with pre-filled value

Tags: javascript, material-components-web, mdc-components

I am pre-filling a few text fields and the border is not visible.
[image]

I am using, for example, the following JavaScript to pre-fill the field(s) but the outline is not rendered until I click /  unclick the field. I tried

```
var doc = document;
doc.getElementById("other-number-tf-ex-input").parentElement.classList.add("mdc-text-field--upgraded");
doc.getElementById("other-number-tf-ex-input").nextElementSibling.classList.add("mdc-text-field__label--float-above");
doc.getElementById("other-number-tf-ex-input").value = values[1].otherPhoneExtensionCode;
window.mdc.autoInit();
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="account-telephone-outlined-wrapper">
    <div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--outlined mdc-text-field--dense tel-medium" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextField">
        <input required pattern="^[0-9]*$" type="text" id="cellular-number-tf-cc-input" class="mdc-text-field__input" aria-controls="cellular-number-tf-cc-message">
        <label for="cellular-number-tf-cc-input" class="mdc-text-field__label">1</label>
        <div class="mdc-text-field__outline">
            <svg>
                <path class="mdc-text-field__outline-path" d=""/>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-text-field__idle-outline"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="mdc-text-field-helper-text mdc-text-field-helper-text--validation-msg" id="cellular-number-tf-cc-message">
        00000
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitly instantiate an MDCTextField object, then set the value:

```
var doc = document;

var field = new mdc.textField.MDCTextField(doc.getElementById("other-number-tf-ex-input-container"));
field.value = values[1].otherPhoneExtensionCode;
```

This just works for me and triggers the floating label.

Pay attention to *other-number-tf-ex-input-container* id: it must point to the container mdc-text-field div.

Answer (score 0):

I only set the normal disabled textfield configuration (the disabled class and input's disabled property) but programatically set the value, such as:

```
myMDCtextfield.value = "myvalue";
```

And that trigger the floating label :)